# Why React Router switch always showing first component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I can try this code line;

```
// This code redirect to as "/" and it's work but example when ı write "/blabla" doesn't show Errorpage
<Switch>
       <Suspense fallback={<div>Daha sonra tekrar deneyin.</div>}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
       </Suspense>
       <Suspense fallback={<div>Daha sonra tekrar deneyin.</div>}>
             <Route component={ErrorPage} />
       </Suspense>
 </Switch>
```

But it’s don’t display an error component on the page.
I found one thing, Which one is at the top of the switch. it’s showing.
Example:

```
// Showing Home Component
<Switch>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Daha sonra tekrar deneyin.</div>}>
        <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
      </Suspense>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Daha sonra tekrar deneyin.</div>}>
        <Route component={ErrorPage} />
      </Suspense>
 </Switch>
```

```
// Showing ErrorPage component
        <Switch>
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Daha sonra tekrar deneyin.</div>}>
            <Route component={ErrorPage} />
          </Suspense>
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Daha sonra tekrar deneyin.</div>}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          </Suspense>
        </Switch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can wrap only 1 suspense and it will work too

Try the below code and see if it works

**/ will render Home and any other route Error Page**

```js
<Switch>
       <Suspense fallback={<div>Daha sonra tekrar deneyin.</div>}>
         //anything wrong in this wrapped suspense will execute fallback
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path='/' component={ErrorPage} />
       </Suspense>
 </Switch>
```

Comment: It worked, but there is a problem. This time both appear in the "/" path. "/" Only the Path Home Page should appear.

Comment: I will attach a sandbox @OyeeRatio

Answer (score 0):

`Route` must be a direct child of `Switch`. So do this instead.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Daha sonra tekrar deneyin.</div>}>
      <Home />
    </Suspense>
  </Route>
  <Route path="*">
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Daha sonra tekrar deneyin.</div>}>
      <ErrorPage />
    </Suspense>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that's not true. I tried this. I wanna "/" this path for the home component. not "/home"

Comment: I changed this code a little and this too worked. First of should remove this (path="*") then this "/home" instead "/".

Comment: Oops, I meant to use `"/"` instead of `"/home"`. Updated accordingly. I add the `"*"` here because it is how the example in the official doc illerstrate.

Answer (score 0):

What the switch does is when it matches a route it won't look for any other component at all. It will always render the first match and will not look any further. Basically, it's useful when it comes to debugging your code.
I guess in your code, you have to define an extra path name for showing the error page.
I hope my answer helped a little.

Answer (score 0):

Put home route below every others route then it will work

```
        <Switch>


            <Route path="/about">
                <About />
            </Route>
            {/* <Route path="/users">
                <Users />
            </Route> */}
            <Route path="/demand">
                <Demand />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
                <Home />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
```